# DELETE WITH INTERSECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-delete, intersect

I have two tables with the same number of columns with no primary keys (I know, this is not my fault). Now I need to delete all rows from table A that exists in table B (they are equal, each one with 30 columns).

The most immediate way I thought is to do a `INNER JOIN` and solve my problem. But, write conditions for all columns (worrying about `NULL`) is not elegant (maybe cause my tables are not elegant either).

I want to use `INTERSECT`. I am not knowing how to do it? This is my first question:

I tried ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1882)):

```
declare @A table (value int, username varchar(20))
declare @B table (value int, username varchar(20))

insert into @A values (1, 'User 1'), (2, 'User 2'), (3, 'User 3'), (4, 'User 4')
insert into @B values (2, 'User 2'), (4, 'User 4'), (5, 'User 5')

DELETE @A 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM @A INTERSECT SELECT * from @B) A
```

But all rows were deleted from table `@A`.

This drived me to second question: why the command `DELETE @A FROM @B` deletes all rows from table `@A`?

Comment: If i remember well, doing DELETE A FROM B does not restrict anything, and this normal that it deletes everything.
you could restrict by doing something like : 
DELETE A FROM B where A.value = B.Value

Adding a FROM after a delete is kind like of a LEFT JOIN

Comment: You meant `DELETE A` and that does not run. Right now you are deleting @A CROSS JOIN (something else). Which deletes everything if there is at least one row in something else. Look at the query plan to see this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE a 
FROM @A a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.* INTERSECT SELECT * FROM @B)
```

Delete from @A where, for each record in @A, there is a match where the record in @A intersects with a record in @B.

This is based on Paul White's [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) using INTERSECT for inequality checking.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1922)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is the syntax I was looking for. It is hard to choose the right answer since I asked two questions. But the best answer for my second question is on comments given by @usr.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question you can delete based on `join`:

```
delete a 
from @a a
join @b b on a.value = b.value and a.username = b.username
```

The second case is really strange. I remember similar case here and many complaints about this behaviour. I will try to fing that question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but I am wanting to avoid the join because the number of columns in my real case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Giorgi's answer to delete the rows you need.

As for the question regarding why all rows were deleted, that's because there is no limiting condition. Your `FROM` clause gets a table to process, but there is no `WHERE` clause to prevent certain rows from being deleted from `@A`.

Comment: Having a table to process isn't sufficient http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1896

Comment: Also consider using EXCEPT instead of INTERSECT if your ultimate goal is to delete from only one of the two tables being compared. The logic and steps would be simpler.

Comment: @MartinSmith - in your sample @A is emptied (deleted...). It's true that if the `FROM` clause is empty, nothing is deleted, but as for what happened in the OP (where the `FROM` clause ISN'T empty...), the reason is as I stated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table (T) defining the primary keys
2. insert all records from A into T (i will assume there are no duplicates in A)
3. try to insert all records from B in T
   3A. if insert fails delete it from B (already exists)
4. Drop T (you really shouldn't !!!)

Answer (score 0):

Giorgi's answer explicitly compares all columns, which you wanted to avoid.
It is possible to write code that doesn't list all columns explicitly.
`EXCEPT` produces the result set that you need, but I don't know a good way to use this result set to `DELETE` original rows from `A` without primary key. So, the solution below saves this intermediary result in a temporary table using `SELECT * INTO`. Then deletes everything from `A` and copies temporary result into `A`. Wrap it in a transaction.

```
-- generate the final result set that we want to have and save it in a temporary table
SELECT *
INTO #t
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM @A
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @B
) AS E;

-- copy temporary result back into A
DELETE FROM @A;

INSERT INTO @A
SELECT * FROM #t;

DROP TABLE #t;

-- check the result
SELECT * FROM @A;
```

**result set**

```
value    username
1        User 1
3        User 3
```

The good side of this solution is that it uses `*` instead of the full list of columns. Of course, you can list all columns explicitly as well. It will still be easier to write and handle, than writing comparisons of all columns and taking care of possible NULLs.